# EF, динамический выбор поля из базы данных для разных языков

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Проблема какая:
В БД есть сущности, например города (Cities), у каждого города есть название на нескольких языках - ru_Name, en_Name и тд.
В коде, я хочу получать те города, которые в названии имеют какой-то текст:
`Cities.Where(x => x.Name.Contains("something"))`
Но, в зависимости от пришедшего в потоке языка (`Thread.CurrentUICulture`), мне, соответственно, необходимо `.Name` заменять на `.ru_Name`, `en_Name` и тд. чтобы поиск был по нужной колонке.

Вопрос: как такое сделать? Это должно быть универсально, так как таких сущностей и полей сотни в проекте.

Предполагаю, что надо использовать ExpressionTree, но с ними опыта никакого и не знаю как подойти к решению данной проблемы.

Comment: Если языков всего пару штук, то просто сделайте метод, который через Switch будет проверять входной язык. Если языков много, то тут скорей всего нужно использовать рекурсию, где вы будете искать нужное свойство.

Comment: В каком формате содержится культура в Thread.CurrentUICulture?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Проблема в том, что языков не пара штук, и свойство Name должно через EF'ный QueryProvider компилироваться в SQL. Но так как Name в таблице нет, то необходимо его заменить на необходимое свойство в зависимости от языка

Comment: @Sergey Не совсем понял вопроса. Что значит "в каком формате" ? Там объект CultureInfo, в котором мне интересно получить `TwoLetterISOLanguageName` чтобы корректно определить какое поле необходимо использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посидев какое-то время в интернете и познавая дзен ExpressionTrees, я всё таки пришёл к решению которое мне нужно - `ExpressionVisitor`
Небольшой пример:

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var cities = new List<City>(Enumerable.Range(0, 30).Select(x => new City { ru_Name = $"ru{x}", en_Name = $"en{x * 2}" }))
                .AsQueryable();
            var exprVisitor = new ExprVisitor();
            var filter = "1";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ru");

            var query = cities
                .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(filter))
                .Visit(exprVisitor); // changing query here

            foreach (var city in query)
                Console.WriteLine(city.Name);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class City
    {
        [ExpressionLocalizable]
        public string Name
        {
            get;set; // здесь должны быть правильные доступы к полям на основе CurrentUICulture, но опустим это
        }

        public string ru_Name { get; set; }

        public string en_Name { get; set; }
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
    public class ExpressionLocalizableAttribute : Attribute { }

    public class ExprVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (node.Member.GetCustomAttribute<ExpressionLocalizableAttribute>() == null)
                return base.VisitMember(node);

            var nodeType = node.Expression.Type;
            var localizedPropertyName = $"{Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName}_{node.Member.Name}";
            var property = nodeType.GetProperty(localizedPropertyName);

            if (property == null)
            {
                throw new NotSupportedException($"No such property '{localizedPropertyName}' in type '{nodeType.Name}'!");
            }

            return Expression.MakeMemberAccess(node.Expression, property);
        }
    }

    public static class QueryExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<TResult> Visit<TResult>(this IQueryable<TResult> query, ExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            var expr = visitor.Visit(query.Expression);
            return query.Provider.CreateQuery<TResult>(expr);
        }
    }
```

Что происходит:
Для модификации Query, используется `ExpressionVisitor`. Данный класс обходит Expression, и в случае когда посещает `MemberExpression`(что является `node.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess`), в данном случае это `x.Name`, проверяется у свойства Name атрибут `ExpressionLocalizable`, который является меткой того, что данное свойство надо будет заменить. А далее формирует имя свойства на которое необходимо заменить, получение данного свойства, и метод возвращает новый `MemberExpression`.
После обхода этим `ExpressionVisitor`ом, я получаю новый Expression, из которого делаю новый IQueryable.

**P.S.**
 1. Для определения что свойство надо заменять я использовал атрибут, соответственно этот атрибут надо расставлять во всех моделях. У меня их +-100, так что если вам лень столько менять - придётся искать другой способ для определения необходимости замены
 2. Если у вас используется механизм кэширования скомпилированных Query/Expression, то после первой компиляции для первого условия (для первого языка) вы уже не получите метод для другого, поэтому необходимо решить проблему кеширования с ключом, основанным на этом условии. (наверно будут решать это через `CuncurrencyCollection<string, Func<>>`, где ключ это язык)
 3. Также, дабы добавить гибкости, можно навесить параметры в атрибут, например чтобы была возможность добавить переопределение названия полей.

Кому интересно посмотреть, этот же пример: [GitHub](https://github.com/Luminisc/ExpressionTreeExample)

Answer (score 0):

```
var sql = $"select * dbo.Cities where dbo.Cities.{{Thread.CurrentUICulture}}_Name like '%{searchText}%'";
await _dbContext.Cities.FromSqlRaw(sql); // in dotnet <3.0 use 'FromSql'
```